# Cannot customize central_meridian through wtk in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I currently need to perform Albert projection on the image and change some of the parameters. The projected coordinate system used is Asia_North_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic. See the official website for details: https://epsg.io/102025. However, the defined parameter 'central_meridian' has not been modified correctly. Specifically, I want to change 'central_meridian' to 105, but the final downloaded image 'central_meridian' is still 0. The specific code is as follows：

var crs = 'PROJCS["Albers_Equal_Area_Conic",
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295],
AXIS["Longitude", EAST],
AXIS["Latitude", NORTH]],
PROJECTION["Albers"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",0],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",105],
PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",25],
PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",47],
PARAMETER["Latitude_of_Origin",0],
UNIT["Meter",1]]';

var proj_albert = ee.Projection(crs);
Export.image.toDrive({
crs: proj_albert,
image: Image,
description: 'HEY',
scale: 30,
region: region,
folder: 'HEY',
maxPixels:1e13
});

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but site epsg.io is not official. It is maintained by the MapTiler team. Official source for EPSG info is https://epsg.org but you can't find 102025 there because it is actually an ESRI code.  Have you tried to introduce false easting instead of editing central meridian?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have tried the false seating, but it's not useful. So, I'm confused.